# Yii2: Rendering view from within the widget

Tags: php, yii2, widget

**What have I tried?**

1. I have created `CustomWidget` by extending `Widget` class
2. In the end of `run` method body I tried to place by different ways calling render method.
3. I have tried this ways

`$this->render( '//widgets/custom' )`

`$this->render( 'custom' )`

`$this->render( '@frontend/views/widgets/custom' )`

`$this->renderFile(/*absolute path to file*/)`

But all in vain.

**And with another view, for example**

`$this->render('//site/404')` - Works

I thought maybe the problem the widget is searching for different directory than all other views.
I have overridden `Widget` method `getViewPath` and intentionally return path to my views. By default `getViewPath` returns .../components/views.
But the error is still exists.
I have tried to place widget directory to components/views, but there is no result.

**Piece of `CustomWidget` code**

```
class CustomWidget extends Widget {
    public function run() {
        return $this->render( '/widgets/custom' );
    }
}
```

I'll be grateful for any clue, suggestion, advice about fixing this problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is **ftp** and **php** users have different groups.

I created file via **ftp** and the file has different group than **php** user started with.

Changing group for the `widgets/custom.php` and group for directory `widgets` to appropriate to `php` and set permission to `0770` fixed that issue.

Comment: I don't think this is the answer. `render()` assumes a folder relative to where you are using it. So in say your `views/site/index.php` file it assumes that `site` folder. If you use: `<?= $this->render('@app/components/views/custom') ?>` it should work. Moreover, if inside that `custom.php` file you have something like `<?= $this->render('custom2') ?>` that would work. The documentation (`https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-widgets#2-utilizing-begin-and-end-methods`) does not make this very clear IMO.

Answer (score 2):

You can render a view like below inside a widget, i am using the `views/site/about.php` view in the following example

```
echo \Yii::$app->view->render('@app/views/site/about');
```

You can use aliases or just `/site/about` in the above line too, but mind the starting `/` which is important in case you are trying to load a view from the application's `view` folder otherwise it will point to the current view folder where the widget is loaded.

Yii2 list of path aliases available with `basic` and `advanced-app`.

**Yii2 Basic App**

- `@app`: Your application root directory
- `@vendor`: Your vendor directory on your root app install directory
- `@runtime`: Your application files runtime/cache storage folder
- `@web`: Your application base url path
- `@webroot`: Your application web root
- `@tests`: Your console tests directory

**Yii2 Advanced App**

- `@app`: Your application root directory (either frontend or backend or console depending on where you access it from)
- `@vendor`: Your vendor directory on your root app install directory
- `@runtime`: Your application files runtime/cache storage folder
- `@web`: Your application base url path
- `@webroot`: Your application web root
- `@tests`: Your console tests directory
- `@common`: Alias for your common root folder on your root app install directory
- `@frontend`: Alias for your frontend root folder on your root app install directory
- `@backend`: Alias for your backend root folder on your root app install directory
- `@console`: Alias for your console root folder on your root app install directory

Answer (score 0):

render does not recognize relative paths that are not relative to its respective controllers, unless you use an alias.

So, if you want to use a path relative to a component or widget, for example:

widgets/MyWidget/MyWidget.php

widgets/MyWidget/views/custom.php

Use this inside MyWidget.php:

```
$this->renderFile(dirname(__FILE__). '/widgets/custom.php' )
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy actually:

```
return (new CommentsWidget())->render('_some_widget_view_name', [
    'comments' => $activeDataProvider
]);
```